# Spring Data. Может ли быть объект не Entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

У меня есть таблица, в которой нет Primary Key. Она не обязана содержать уникальные данные как в любом из полей, так и в любом их сочетании, т.е. я не могу даже сделать Composite Primary Key. Мне надо вычитывать из неё строки по одной, желательно в порядке их добавления (но не обязательно, можно и в произвольном порядке).

Все примеры со Spring Data JPA что я видел основаны на Entity, т.е. обязаны иметь уникальный ID, что в данном случае неприменимо.

Вопрос: можно ли работать с такой таблицей средствами Spring Data (кроме как написанием прямого SQL-запроса)?

Comment: Зачем вам таблица в которой нет привязки к уникальным значениями может повторяться одна и та же строка?
мука-мука-мука, вторая запись мука-мука-мука. И как вы выберете вторую запись? Есть ли логическое обоснование такой структуры?

Comment: Таблица мне дана как данность, на которую я не могу повлиять, поэтому вопрос "зачем" не стоит :) В эту таблицу прилетают "события", которые я обрабатываю. Строки с одинаковыми данными - однотипные события, каждое последующее гарантировано "перекрывает" предыдущее. Значит из кучки одинаковых событий мне достаточно обработать одно. После обработки событие из этой таблицы удаляется (т.е. убьются все одинаковые строки).

Answer (score 1):

Этот случай описан в документации в разделе [нет первичного ключа](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key):

> If your table truly has no unique columns, then use all of the columns as the id. Typically when this occurs the data is read-only, so even if the table allows duplicate rows with the same values, the objects will be the same anyway, so it does not matter that JPA thinks they are the same object.

Перевод:

> Если в вашей таблице действительно нет уникальных столбцов, используйте все столбцы в качестве идентификатора [сущности]. Обычно такое случается, когда данные только для чтения, так что даже если у таблице будут дубликаты строк с одинаковыми значениями, объекты будут точно такими же, так что не имеет значения, что JPA считает их одним и тем же объектом.

Так что сделайте составной ключ на все колонки и сделайте сущность только для чтения. Это можно сделать запретив модификации самой сущности (т.е. не создавать сеттеры и использовать аннотации на полях) плюс добавив `@EntityListeners` на класс сущности в слушателем, который бросает исключения в методах типа `onPrePersist`.

Answer (score 1):

В параграфе: [Java Persistence: Identity and Sequencing : No Primary Key](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key) предлагаются следующие варианты:

- Добавить сгенерированный идентификатор Id в таблицу и entity-класс (например, UUID)
- *Иногда*, если существует столбец / набор столбцов, имеющих *уникальные* значения, можно использовать его как Id в JPA.  Также JPA Id не всегда должен соответствовать первичному ключу таблицы в БД, и не являются обязательными ограничения по первичному ключу/уникальному значению

> The JPA Id does not always have to match the database table primary key constraint, nor is a primary key or a unique constraint required.

- Если действительно нет уникальных столбцов, можно использовать все столбцы как Id.  Обычно такая ситуация возникает, когда данные используются только для чтения, поэтому даже если в таблице будут попадаться дубликаты, объекты будут одинаковы.  В случае изменения/удаления данных все дублированные строки будут изменены/удалены.

> Typically when this occurs the data is read-only, so even if the table allows duplicate rows with the same values, the objects will be the same anyway, so it does not matter that JPA thinks they are the same object. The issue with allowing updates and deletes is that there is no way to uniquely identify the object's row, so all of the matching rows will be updated or deleted.